# Floating menu div css

Tags: css

Trying to make a floating css menu. How do I get the floating div to float relative to parent container?

http://jsfiddle.net/Ve8vC/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using
`postion:fixed` you should be using `postion:absolute` for #float-menu.

Position fixed should be used when you want to fix something with respect to position of window (no matter you scroll how much or to where). Position absolute will deliver the same effect except it gets fixed to wherever it was rendered with respect to body. Putting position absolute with parent positioned to relative will deliver the effect which you are trying to achieve however it will not sustain if you scroll down.

Best solution would be to change the attribute position to absolute as soon as scrolltop crosses 100px using javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You should place your menu div inside the container